# Python list comprehension: test function return

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is there a way to test the return of a function in a list (or dict) comprehension? I'd like to avoid writing that:

```
lst = []
for x in range(10):
  bar = foo(x)
  if bar:
    lst.append(bar)
```

and use a list comprehension instead. Obviously, I don't want to write:

```
[foo(x) for x in range(10) if foo(x)]
```

so?

```
[foo(x) for x in range(10) if ??? ]
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use the first way? It's the appropriate way.

Comment: @Rohit Jain -- depending on `foo`, it could be an expensive operation which you don't want to do twice.

Comment: @mgilson: And in the first example, he only does it once.

Comment: @TimPietzcker -- Ahh... I thought Rohit was refering to the first list-comprehension... I'm following the comment stream now.  Thanks.

Comment: @TimPietzcker.. Yeah I was talking about 1st list comprehension only.

Comment: @mgilson: Obviously you *were* right. Cheers!

Comment: @TimPietzcker -- Argv!  As soon as I think I get to the same page as everyone else, I find out they were on page I just left.  :)

Comment: @mgilson: Argv? You surely mean Argc! Right? ;)

Comment: For various reasons:
- for equal readability, I prefer conciseness
- list comprehension are faster
- intellectual stimulation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about

```
filter(None, map(foo, range(10)))
```

If you don't want to keep the intermediate list, replace `map()` with [`itertools.imap()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap). And with [`itertools.ifilter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter), the whole thing could be turned into a generator.

```
itertools.ifilter(None, itertools.imap(foo, range(10)))
```

Comment: Or, rather than `imap`, you could use a genexp:  `filter(None,(foo(x) for x in range(10)))`

Answer (score 5):

Just make a generator to compute the values and build the filtered list from the generator afterwards.

Example:

```
# create generator via generator expression
results = (foo(x) for x in xrange(10))
# build result list, not including falsy values
filtered_results = [i for i in results if i]
```

For reference:

- https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator
- https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/