# When function can only be called once

Tags: python

The way it is I can only call `funct()` once per iteration. So I can't do this:

```
result=[funct(arg) for arg in args if arg and funct(arg)]
```

If there is a connection drop this function returns `None`. If None is returned I don't want to add it to the resulted list. How to achieve it?

```
def funct(arg):
    if arg%2: return arg*2

args=[1,2,3,None,4,5]

result=[funct(arg) for arg in args if arg] 
print result
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python list comprehension: test function return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632280/python-list-comprehension-test-function-return)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filter as you will not be returning any `0` values to your list:

```
result = filter(None,map(funct,filter(None,args)))
```

It will filter your `args` list and any `None` values returned

On a list with 20 elements args:

```
In [18]: %%timeit                   

[val for arg in args
              if arg                 
              for val in [funct(arg)]
              if val is not None]
   ....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.6 µs per loop

In [19]: timeit filter(None,map(funct,filter(None,args)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.42 µs per loop

In [20]: timeit [a for a in [funct(arg) for arg in args if arg] if a]

100000 loops, best of 3: 7.98 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

you can nest comprehensions

```
result=[a for a in [funct(arg) for arg in args if arg] if a]
```